# I can't change the textview text by pressing a button

Tags: android, button, textview

Hello all I am struggling to change the textview text dynamically in android studio i get 0 errors but when i am testing the program runs but at the time i press the button program crashes

CODE:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment { TextView tv;

Button[] btn = new Button[30];
TextView tv;



@Override
public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    btn[i] = new Button(getActivity());
    btn[i].setText("1");
    btn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`
    btn[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn[i].setId(i);
    linearLayout.addView(btn[i]);



btn[2].setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);


Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {



 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (v == btn[2]) {

            tv.setText(btn[2].getText());
        }

    }
};
```

This is not the all parts of the code(there are 2 fragments this is one of them) but i can't share all of the program itself, but these are all the parts about my problem. If you have anything to say please say it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the error you get on crash.

Comment: It says "Unfortunately Your Program is now shutting down" on the phone screen when i press the button specified in the code

Comment: The way you posted your code it shouldn't even compile. Check again or add proper code we can work with..

Comment: yes there are some parts missing i intentionally didnt post them here its illegal for the company i work with but you can understand what is my point with this post . i am sorry that i cant post all the code here :(

Comment: No, I can't understand, sorry.

Comment: Instead of `v == btn[2]` try something like this `v.getId() == btn[2].getId()`.

Comment: i generate 30 buttons and when i press one of them, its text will be the textviews text too,

Comment: @G.T. thanks mate but it didn't work

Comment: those button are displying in view  ? i asked bcz linearLayout view is not added in parent view which is inflated in onCreateView

Comment: yes they are displaying in view

Comment: oops forgot to mention there are 2 fragments this is just one of them

Comment: @AykutDos TextView tv instance is created ? from the myFragmentView  view

Comment: yes yes it is it works fine in an another class but this one doesn't work but other class has extends Activity part this one don't it can be the problem but i can't find a way to solve it @user1140237

Comment: Where do you initialize the "tv" variable? If it is null then you will get a crash in onClick()

Comment: @samgak i just edited my post you can see my tv variable initializitaion

Comment: add this test: if(tv != null) tv.setText(btn[2].getText()); Maybe it's not finding R.id.textView1 correctly.

Comment: @samgak yes you are right thank you so much but how can i overcome this?

Comment: open fragmentlayout.xml (both landscape and portrait) and double check that textView1 is in there and not in some other file

Comment: What if it must be in the main.xml? Can i solve this problem without putting the textview in fragmentlayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If textView1 is in your main Activity and not in your fragment then `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` will return null. If you want to set the text view in your main Activity from the fragment, then do it by calling a public method on the main Activity.

Add a method like this to your main Activity:

```
public void setTextViewText(String text)
{
     TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     if(textview != null)
         textview.setText(text);
}
```

Then change your Button.OnClickListener in your fragment to call the method:

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn[2])
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setTextViewText(btn[2].getText());
    }
};
```

Change `MainActivity` to the name of your main Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

With an incomplete code is kinda hard to understand where the error might be.

You bind to the btn[2] an onClickListener ,

```
btn[2].setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
```

but you define it after binding it.

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new
    Button.OnClickListener() {
 ...
}
```

Maybe you have a global listener that makes you run the code(not visible in the source you posted)? This would mean you bind to a valid-but-empty listener, while the real one is created only afterward.
Something like

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // does nothing 
  };
 };

@Override
protected void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  /* 
   * for loop creating buttons
  */

  btn[2].setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

  Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v == btn[2]) tv.setText(btn[2].getText());
    }
  };
```

Just guessing

Comment: good guess but no there isn't second listener thank you so much for your help

Comment: might be possible you just think you are hitting the right button while it's not? :P btn[2] will be the third button, not the second.

still, just a second guess :P

Comment: plus, commenting here because i don't have enough rep to do in the main topic-comment section.

v == btn[2] is NOT WRONG , the objects are fine to be the same thing, so == works